# What happens internally and raises ValueError while using bitwise and comparison operators with numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, expression, bitwise-operators, comparison-operators

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([3, 4, 6, 15, 25, 38])


print(arr > 5 & arr <= 20)

"""Output
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(arr > 5 & arr <= 20)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
"""
```

I know this error occurs because I have missed the parenthesis around conditions. But I want to know in which order the expression is evaluated and what causes this error.

Comment: `print((arr > 5) & (arr <= 20))`

Comment: Yeah I know it will solve the error, I want to know the evaluation order of this expression and at what point it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` has a [higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `<=`, so this is being run as `arr > (5 & arr) <= 20` [and since comparison operators are chained](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), this is the equivalent of:

```
(arr > (5 & arr)) and (arr <= (5 & arr))
```

And this causes the well known error because you cannot use arrays in a boolean context, as the error message explains... (Side note, `5 & arr` is only evaluated once...)

So consider, even this will fail:

```
>>> arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> 0 < arr < 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```